# Magento 2: Catalog rules in custom ui form is empty on editing

Tags: magento-2.2.1, catalog-rules

I am working on extension in which I have add catalog rules conditions in my UI form. I am storing as serialized condition. It saves perfectly. However, I am getting empty field during edit form.
[image]